# join multiple tables but gives me multiple results per line

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi i'm trying to join multiple tables but my main table contains null values as foreign keys so i if i want all my information about my artikelen i have to check null to. When i execute my query i receive my information but ever line is displayed like three times or so.  I can't figure out why

```
SELECT DISTINCT Artikelen.*, BtwTarieven.*, Eenheden.*, Categorieen.*, Leveranciers.IdLeverancier, Leveranciers.Naam, Leveranciers.Actief
FROM Artikelen 
    JOIN BtwTarieven
        ON (BtwTarieven.IdBtwTarief = Artikelen.IdBtwTarief OR Artikelen.IdBtwTarief IS NULL)
    JOIN Eenheden
        ON (Eenheden.IdEenheid = Artikelen.IdEenheid OR Artikelen.IdEenheid IS NULL)
    JOIN Categorieen
        ON (Categorieen.IdCategorie = Artikelen.IdCategorie OR Artikelen.IdCategorie IS NULL)
    Join Leveranciers
        ON (Leveranciers.IdLeverancier = Artikelen.IdStandaardLeverancier OR Artikelen.IdStandaardLeverancier IS NULL)
```

Comment: Show sample data and desired results.  Multiple lines are showing because the join generates all the possible combinations, so some tables have multiple rows for the data you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Artikelen.*, BtwTarieven.*, Eenheden.*, Categorieen.*, Leveranciers.IdLeverancier, Leveranciers.Naam, Leveranciers.Actief
FROM Artikelen 
LEFT JOIN BtwTarieven
    ON (BtwTarieven.IdBtwTarief = Artikelen.IdBtwTarief )
LEFT JOIN Eenheden
    ON (Eenheden.IdEenheid = Artikelen.IdEenheid )
LEFT JOIN Categorieen
    ON (Categorieen.IdCategorie = Artikelen.IdCategorie )
LEFT JOIN Leveranciers
    ON (Leveranciers.IdLeverancier = Artikelen.IdStandaardLeverancier )
```